# VA-API on i915 hardware in Debian

Tags: debian, intel-graphics, video-playback

I have an old Atom laptop (VGA device ID [22B1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_graphics_processing_units)) which I would like to use as a video player.  I vaguely remember I used to have accelerated video on in with Debian Stretch, many years ago, but I may be mistaken. The laptop currently has Debian Buster installed, with `i915.ko` driver loaded, and VA-API refuses to work:

```
user@machine:~/.config$ vainfo
libva info: VA-API version 1.4.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)
vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit

user@machine:~/.config$ LIBVADRIVERNAME=i915 vainfo
libva info: VA-API version 1.4.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
libva info: User requested driver 'i915'
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/i915_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit
```

I understand that `i915_drv_video.so` is not provided by any Debian Buster package. I tried using `i965_drv_video.so` and `iHD_drv_video.so`, but `vainfo` reports "init failed", which is not surprising considering that I have i915.

I wonder what my options are. Is it worth a shot to upgrade to Bullseye? Or to downgrade to Stretch? As far as I can tell, `i915_drv_video.so` is not provided by any of these either.

Here's the active configuration of the `i915` driver:

```
user@machine:~/.config$ sudo systool -m i915 -av
Module = "i915"

  Attributes:
    coresize            = "1331200"
    initsize            = "0"
    initstate           = "live"
    refcnt              = "3"
    taint               = ""
    uevent              = <store method only>

  Parameters:
    alpha_support       = "N"
    disable_display     = "N"
    disable_power_well  = "1"
    dmc_firmware_path   = "(null)"
    edp_vswing          = "0"
    enable_dc           = "-1"
    enable_dp_mst       = "Y"
    enable_dpcd_backlight= "N"
    enable_fbc          = "0"
    enable_guc          = "0"
    enable_gvt          = "N"
    enable_hangcheck    = "Y"
    enable_ips          = "1"
    enable_ppgtt        = "2"
    enable_psr          = "-1"
    error_capture       = "Y"
    fastboot            = "N"
    force_reset_modeset_test= "N"
    guc_firmware_path   = "(null)"
    guc_log_level       = "0"
    huc_firmware_path   = "(null)"
    invert_brightness   = "0"
    load_detect_test    = "N"
    lvds_channel_mode   = "0"
    mmio_debug          = "0"
    modeset             = "-1"
    nuclear_pageflip    = "N"
    panel_use_ssc       = "-1"
    prefault_disable    = "N"
    reset               = "2"
    vbt_firmware        = "(null)"
    vbt_sdvo_panel_type = "-1"
    verbose_state_checks= "Y"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that VAAPI is only supported on [Intel® GMA X4500HD and above](https://01.org/linuxmedia/vaapi) while your [Intel GMA900](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_GMA#GMA_900) may only support the previous incarnation known as [X-Video Motion Compensation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Video_Motion_Compensation) (XvMC).

It also sounds like whatever video acceleration available is limited to MPEG-2. While you will be able to play DVDs you will not have hardware acceleration for Blue rays and modern web video. From the [Intel GMA900](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_GMA#GMA_900) Wikipedia information:

> Like previous Intel integrated graphics parts, the GMA 900 has hardware support for MPEG-2 motion compensation, color-space conversion and DirectDraw overlay.

[Arch Linux has some information on XvMC](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XvMC), but I can only find [vague forum posts about Debian](https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=32392).

Comment: Looking at [this](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1829124) post it seems that XvMC on old Intel chips is anyway limited to DVD resolutions, where it is practically useless as software rendering is fast enough.

Comment: Nevertheless, the corresponding package seems to be present: https://packages.debian.org/en/buster/xserver-xorg-video-intel

Comment: The first link gives a "You are not authorized to access this page"

Comment: Could you help me understand how you concluded "Intel GMA900" from the OP? When I followed the link for and searched for the device ID 22B1 I only found devices from around 2016, while GMA900 is from ~2004.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually have an i915 – that's only the name of the kernel driver; the same giant `i915.ko` driver handles all Intel GPUs ever made in the past ~17 years or so, even though **none** of them except for the original Intel GMA 9xx series (which was several generations before your HD Graphics) have actually been called "i915".

However, the naming is only *similar,* but not identical between the kernel driver and the various types of userspace drivers, so it's completely normal that you see i915.ko on the kernel side but i965.so in VAAPI.

For example, the Mesa project has separate DRI drivers `i915_dri.so` and `i965_dri.so` (as well as `crocus_dri` and `iris_dri`) for different generations of Intel GPUs – all four of those expect to talk to i915.ko on the kernel side.

Same goes for VA-API; the `i965_drv_video.so` VA-API driver *is* the correct one for most older Intel GPUs, while `iHD_drv_video.so` is for Skylake and later, but all of them would still use the i915.ko kernel driver.

(As far as I can tell, there is no i915_drv_video.so because *actual* "i915" GPUs didn't have accelerated video decoding at all.)

Comment: It may all be true, but what is the conclusion? The OP asks for a practical advice: "I wonder what my options are. Is it worth a shot to upgrade to Bullseye? Or to downgrade to Stretch?" Frankly I don't even know if your answer should be interpreted as "there is no way" or what.

Comment: I already tried `i965_drv_video.so` which makes `vainfo` fail with "init failed" error. Does that mean my GPU has no VA-API support, or is there anything else I could check before giving up?